# VBA: How do I write an If statement using a true/false method and VLookup code?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

I struggled with phrasing the question title, sorry. I created a VBA form. In the `linebx` combo bx I have the following code, that prefills the `PilotBx` and `TailBx` text boxes.

My issue is when the linebx is filled in with a value that is not in that linebx drop down (not in the VLookup range) it sends an error message

> "Runtime error ‘1004’: Unable to get the VLookup property of the worksheetFunction class"

I know what this means, I'm just not sure how to get around it.

I need the code to prefill the `PilotBx` and `TailBx` text boxes, if the `LineBx` matches, the drop down (VLookup range) and if it doesn't I need it to accept the `LineBx`number entered and leave the `PilotBx` and `TailBx` text boxes blank.

Please let me know if you have any questions or details I can give to help. Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is a visual for the form I created:

[image]

```
    Dim z As Double
    Dim h As Double
    Dim k As String
    
        z = LineBx.Value
        h = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LineBx.Value, Sheets("StepBrief").Range("A2:E43"), 1, False)
    
    If h = z Then
        k = True
        
    Else
        k = False
        
    End If
    
    If k = True Then
        TailBx.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(z, Sheets("StepBrief").Range("A2:E43"), 3, False)
        PilotBx.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(z, Sheets("StepBrief").Range("A2:E43"), 2, False)
    
    Else
        TailBx.Value = ""
        PilotBx.Value = ""
        
    End If
```

Comment: Try on error resume next? Edit: better to loop through your range and check for your linebx value.

Comment: Instead of the 'if h=z etc' you can just say 'k=h=z'.  Also 'If k=true' can be replaced by just 'if k'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508472/vba-excel-iferror-vlookup-error

Answer (score 0):

You can go with:

```
Dim h As Double
Dim k As String
    
z = LineBx.Value
h = -1
on error resume next
h = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LineBx.Value, Sheets("StepBrief").Range("A2:E43"), 1, False)
on error goto 0
```

It executes you lookup, does not raise an error when lookup not found. h will be -1 what will not be equal to z. You can use any value to set h to as long as it will not be equal to z you are good.

Answer (score 0):

I suppressed the error message by adding `On Error Resume Next` to *the top*  **and** "Cleared" the `PilotBx` and `TailBx` I felt like that was a cheap way to get around it, but it did work.

```
    z = LineBx.Value
    
On Error Resume Next
    TailBx.Value = ""
    PilotBx.Value = ""

    TailBx.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(z, Sheets("StepBrief").Range("A2:E43"), 3, False)
    PilotBx.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(z, Sheets("StepBrief").Range("A2:E43"), 2, False)
```

Comment: Any credit to @findwindow ?